# Synchronous cross domain javascript call, waiting for response - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

**Disclaimer**
Firstly, a disclaimer: I am working within specific boundaries, so whilst it may seem I'm going about something the long way round, I am limited as to what I can do.  I *know* I should be doing this entirely differently, but I *cannot*.  If it's not possible to do what I'm trying to do here, then that's fine, I just need to know.

---

**Background**
Basically, this boils down to a cross-domain javascript call.  However, I need to wait for the response before returning the method.

Say I have a page - example1.com/host.html.  This contains a javascript method of 'ProvideValue()' which returns an int.  ***Edit**: This method must be executed where it is found, since it may need to access other resources within that domain, and access global variables set for the current session.*

*https://example1.com/host.html*

```
function ProvideValue(){
 return 8;  // In reality, this will be a process that returns a value
}
```

This host.html page contains an iframe pointing to example2.com/content.html (**note the different domain**).  This content.html page contains a method that needs to display the value from host.html in an alert.

*https://example2.com/content.html*

```
function DisplayValue(){
 var hostValue = //[get value from ProvideValue() in host.html]
 alert(hostValue);
}
```

That's it.

**Limitations**
I can run any javascript I like on the host.html, but nothing server-side.  On content.html I can run javascript and anything server-side.  I have no control over the example1.com domain, but full control over example2.com.

**Question**
**How can I retrieve the value from ProvideValue() on example1.com/host.html within the DisplayValue() method on example2.com/content.html?**

---

**Previous Attempts**
Now, I've tried many of the cross-domain techniques, but all of them (that I've found) use an asynchronous callback.  That won't work in this case, because I need to make the request to the host.html, and receive the value back, all within the scope of a single method on the content.html.

The only solution I got working involved relying on asynchronous cross-domain scripting (using easyXDM), and a server-side list of requests/responses in example2.com.  The DisplayValue() method made the request to host.html, then immediately made a synchronous post to the server.  The server would then wait until it got notified of the response from the cross-domain callback.  Whilst waiting, the callback would make another call to the server to store the response.  It worked fine in FireFox and IE, but Chrome wouldn't execute the callback until DisplayValue() completed.  If there is no way to address my initial question, and this option has promise, then I will pose this as a new question, but I don't want to clutter this question with multiple topics.

Comment: I wonder why no one asked, but *why* has the request to be synchronous?

Comment: @FelixKling The DisplayValue method is going to be called by some third-party javascript that I have no control over.  I'm essentially acting as a middle-man between third-party content in example2.com and a third-party host in example1.com.  The calling javascript is expecting a value back from that method, so a callback wouldn't work.

Comment: I see, I assumed something like this. Too bad that third party code is often so inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

Use XMLHttpRequest with [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) to make synchronous cross-domain requests.

If the server doesn't support cors, use a proxy which adds the appropriate CORS headers, e.g. https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ (source code at https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere).

### Example 1: Using synchronous XHR with CORS

```
function getProvidedValue() {
    var url = 'http://example.com/';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // third param = false  = synchronous request
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + url, false);
    xhr.send();
    var result = xhr.responseText;
    // do something with response (text manipulation, *whatever*)
    return result;
}
```

---

### Example 2: Use `postMessage`

If it's important to calculate the values on the fly with session data, use `postMessage` to continuously update the state:

Top-level document (host.html):

```
<script src="host.js"></script>
<iframe name="content" src="https://other.example.com/content.html"></iframe>
```

`host.js`

```
(function() {
    var cache = {
        providedValue: null,
        otherValue: ''
    };
    function sendUpdate() {
        if (frames.content) { // "content" is the name of the iframe
            frames.content.postMessage(cache, 'https://other.example.com');
        }
    }
    function recalc() {
        // Update values
        cache.providedValue = provideValue();
        cache.otherValue = getOtherValue();

        // Send (updated) values to frame
        sendUpdate();
    }

    // Listen for changes using events, pollers, WHATEVER
    yourAPI.on('change', recalc);

    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        if (event.origin !== 'https://other.example.com') return;
        if (event.data === 'requestUpdate') sendUpdate();
    });
})();
```

A script in `content.html`: content.js

```
var data = {}; // Global
var parentOrigin = 'https://host.example.com';
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.origin !== parentOrigin) return;
    data = event.data;
});
parent.postMessage('requestUpdate', parentOrigin);

// To get the value:
function displayValue() {
    var hostName = data.providedValue;
}
```

This snippet is merely a demonstration of the concept. If you want to apply the method, you probably want to split the login in the `recalc` function, such that the value is only recalculated on the update of that particular value (instead of recalculating everything on every update).

Comment: Does that proxy mean that no change is needed on the host (parent) domain?

Comment: @evilbhonda Yes, no changes are necessary. The most beautiful thing about the web service (disclosure: I've created it) is that it can easily be dropped in existing code to overcome cross-domain issues. Simply prefix the URL with `"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"`, add `setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');`, and the cross-domain issues are solved.

Comment: Awesome.  Now, how would I use that to call the ProvideValue() javascript method in host.html?

Comment: @evilbhonda The method I've showed just retrieves the (HTML/JS) source code of the resource. Parse the result yourself using JavaScript's string manipulation (and/or regex) functions to get the desired result.

Comment: Ah, the ProvideValue() must be executed where it is found, as there is likely to be other resources within that domain that it accesses, and is likely to maintain state for the current session.  Sorry for not making that clear in the post.

Comment: @evilbhonda Is the value created by `ProvideValue()` ever going to change after creating the iframe? If not, then you can calculate the value of `ProvideValue()` in advance, and pass the data to the iframe through the `src` or `name` property.

Comment: Yes, the value will definitely change, I'm afraid.  Otherwise the pre-emptive passing of data to the iframe would be a perfect idea!

Comment: @evilbhonda Is it expensive to calculate the value? How often does it change? If the answers to these questions are reasonable, use postMessage to continuously pass the latest value to the frame.

Comment: That's definitely an option, however I'd like to explore other, less intensive options first.  Theoretically, this could work.  However, in practice, there will be hundreds of these methods, the values of which some will rarely change, and others change very frequently, and I don't know how well it will scale.

Comment: @evilbhonda You're giving too little information about the kind of data you want to pass around. If they're generated as a response to an event, bind an event listener that updates some value. You can cache all existing values, and send the whole object with information on update.

Comment: I'm trying hard to keep the question as generic as possible.  There is a reason why I phrased the question as I did, because there are other factors at play that will only work with a request - response communication.  I'm not trying to be difficult, and I appreciate your time so far, I just think I'm trying to do the impossible!

Comment: @evilbhonda I've added an example of my lastly suggested method to my answer. A similar method is used by YouTube's Iframe API, where the incremental updates of the player state is sent several times per second to the parent window, so don't worry about scale too quickly.